# How do you confirm django is using memcached?

Tags: django, memcached

I have a python django webserver that I am trying to use memcached to make it faster.

I have downloaded and installed memcached and started it a user called virtual as follows:

```
/usr/local/bin/memcached -u virtual &
```

on the django setting.py, I have put the memcached server as this:

```
MEMCACHE_HOSTS = ['192.168.101.1:11211']
```

I can do telnet 192.168.101.1 11211 and stats, I do see some statistics there etc.

How do I really know if my django server utilizing the memcached? Is there directory that I can look at or some files to confirm?

Thank you for any insight.

content of manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

from the command line:

```
phthon

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
```

and when I do this:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
```

I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can test cache in Django's shell (`python manage.py shell`):

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.set('foo', 'bar', 600)
>>> cache.get('foo')
'bar'
```

If `cache.get()` returns the set value it means that cache is working as it should. Otherwise it will return `None`.

An other option is to start memcached with `$ memcached -vv`, since it will log all the cache accesses to the terminal. Or alternatively you can install monitoring tool for memcached (i.e. [memcache-top](https://code.google.com/p/memcache-top/)) and check that something is happening in memcached while using your app.

Comment: Blenkus, when I do python manage.py shell, I get bunch of errors: 
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named graphite.app_settings

Comment: Looks like Django can't find settings file. Do you have ```settings.py``` file in root directory of your project? Otherwise you have to set ```DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE``` correctly (in ```manage.py``` file). Normaly it is something like ```<your_project.settings>```.

Comment: Then check this to configure memcached in settings file: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#setting-up-the-cache

Comment: Blenkus, I installed python-memcached and in settings.py, I included these lines: if MEMCACHE_HOSTS:
    CACHES['default'] = {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': MEMCACHE_HOSTS,
        'TIMEOUT': DEFAULT_CACHE_DURATION,
        'KEY_PREFIX': MEMCACHE_KEY_PREFIX,
    }
and in local_settings, I inclduded these lines: MEMCACHE_HOSTS = ['51.16.48.94:11211']
MEMCACHE_KEY_PREFIX = 'graphite'
FIND_CACHE_DURATION = 1500
FIND_TOLERANCE = 2 * FIND_CACHE_DURATION
DEFAULT_CACHE_DURATION = 1500, when I recycle apache, I get server 500 err.

Comment: This is totaly different topic now :). But anyway, check apache and uwsgi logs for errors. If all is normal, set up logging to file for Django (http://ianalexandr.com/blog/getting-started-with-django-logging-in-5-minutes.html). It would be a lot easier if you would use Django development server for debugging (```python manage.py runserver``` and ```DEBUG = True``` in settings).

Comment: Blenkus, I have created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774117/how-do-you-point-graphite-to-memcache

Comment: "if this works it means that cache is working as it should. Otherwise it would throw error."  ... `get` always returns `None` for me, and there is no error.

Comment: @run_the_race I took the liberty to fix that to the answer.