# how do you point graphite to memcache

Tags: django, memcached, graphite

I have a graphite instance that I would like to use memcache server to read from cache.

I have done these:

Installed memcached on 192.168.101.1

Installed graphite and python-memcached on server 192.168.101.2

I verified that graphite web-app works using opentsdb as backend storage. This is my local_settings.py looks like:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'pass123'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

DEBUG = True
MEMCACHE_HOSTS = ['192.168.101.2:11211']
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': '/opt/graphite/storage/graphite.db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
#
STORAGE_FINDERS = (
    'graphite_opentsdb.finder.OpenTSDBFinder',
)

OPENTSDB_URI = 'http://192.168.101.17:4242/api/v1/'
OPENTSDB_TREE = 1

CACHES = {
    'default': {
       'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
       'LOCATION': '192.168.101.2:11211',
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

When I have something in my MEMCACHE_HOST line as shown MEMCACHE_HOSTS = ['192.168.101.2:11211']), I get server error. If I keep it empty or comment out the whole line, I dont see any request going into the memchache host.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you get more debug information on this issue. What is the server error being returned?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I also see this in graphite_log: 
[Tue Apr 21 10:06:43 2015] [error] [client 29.0.89.11]     import memcache
[Tue Apr 21 10:06:43 2015] [error] [client 29.0.89.11] ImportError: No module named memcache
I did install python-memcached library.

Comment: If I go to python shell and type import memcache, no errors.

Comment: @MattWritesCode, I was able to figure out the what I did wrong. I had to change the permission on the python-memcached package. However, I have a problem. I increased the caching to 30 minutes and I started getting this error: "Exception: Failed after 5 retry! See: Unable to save data of type <type 'dict'> to cache", does this mean my memcached server ran out of memory?