# How to stop Django if memcached isn't working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, memcached, throttling

I am looking for a way to stop Django at start up if my memcached isn't working. Is there a way or best practice ?

I'm  using memcached with DRF, specifically with throttling and the throttling mandatory.

Thx for reading.

Flave

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707274/how-do-you-confirm-django-is-using-memcached/29709199 
Also, what do you mean "at start up"? Do you want to check it from your project code?

Comment: I want to check in dev, staging and prod environment if memcached is properly installed and configured. Thx @IgorBelkov for your answer.